# Java - Ubuntu server file not found exception

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

So I just recently switched over to Ubuntu to host my java program. When I run my 
application all of my configuration files are not found (No such file or directory).

Now, I never had this problem with windows & I was able to fix it on my desktop ubuntu when running it through eclipse.

However when I use a sh script in order to execute my application the exceptions are still thrown. All of my files are on the server I know that for a fact, so I decided to printout the absolute paths of my workspace both when using my desktop & when using my server.

```
Desktop:path sent=data/cache/
local=/home/adam/Dropbox/Arios/Source
Attempted file=/home/adam/Dropbox/Arios/Source/data/cache/main_file_cache.idx255
```

This is my current SH script:

```
java -server -Xms512m -Xmx1536m -XX:NewSize=32m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent -XX:+AggressiveOpts -cp /arios/bin org.arios.Main Arios false true false false true

Ubuntu Server: path sent=data/cache/
local=/root
Attempted file=/root/data/cache/main_file_cache.idx255
```

The problem here is that my files are located at root/arios not root/. If you could tell me how to fix this problem on linux I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are executing the script using cron.

If that's so, the script is getting executed by root, and lies you problem.

You should delete that cron job and create one using this command:

```
crontab -u Arios -e
```

It will create a cron job, but it will be executed as Arios.

Comment: No I don't use a cron. I just run the sh script through the terminal.

Comment: and you run it while beeing logged in as Arios?

Comment: oh, sorry. I read your question again, and I was completely wrong. I misread it.

Comment: Arios is just my application name.